# How to remove margins (indents) in richEditControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I configured `richEditControl` with the following code.

```
richEditControl1.Options.HorizontalRuler.Visibility = RichEditRulerVisibility.Hidden;
richEditControl1.Options.VerticalRuler.Visibility = RichEditRulerVisibility.Hidden;
 
richEditControl1.Document.Sections [0] .Margins.Left = Units.InchesToDocumentsF (0f);
richEditControl1.Document.Sections [0] .Margins.Right = Units.InchesToDocumentsF (0f);
 
richEditControl1.Document.Sections [0] .Margins.Top = Units.InchesToDocumentsF (0f);
```

The ultimate goal is to customize the appearance of `richEditControl` as`richTextBox`.
 
**Question:** How to remove the fields that form along the perimeter?

**Picture 1**
[image]

**Picture 2**
[image]

Comment: Not in a position to test but I think this maybe what you need.. https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl.ActiveViewType.property specifically the simple view

Comment: @steve16351 I think you should make your answer. Answer: `richEditControl1.ActiveViewType = RichEditViewType.Simple;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `ActiveViewType` property of the `RichEditControl` to change to a different type of view which doesn't have this outer page border.

The documentation for this property can be found [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraRichEdit.RichEditControl.ActiveViewType.property), what you want in your case is the `RichEditViewType.Simple` setting. You can use it as follows:

```
richEditControl1.ActiveViewType = RichEditViewType.Simple;
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no ActiveViewType try adding a reference to DevExpress.RichEdit.v21.1.Core , it could be missing.